Abstract base class function pointer python
I'd like to make an abstraction of one of my api classes to resolve the following problem. Let's say I have a base class like:
class AbstractAPI(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def create(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def delete(self):
        pass

And a concrete class:
class API(AbstractAPI):
    def create(self):
        print("create")

    def delete(self):
        print("delete")

When requests come in, I don't have access to my API instance. Both due multithreading and to avoid some circular imports. At that point I do know which method I would like to call later. So my plan was to put a function pointer of AbstractAPI onto a queue and wait until I do have access to the API instance.
function_pointer=AbstractAPI.create
# later on ...
function_pointer(ConcreteAPIInstance)

At that point call the function pointer onto the API instance, ba da bim, ba da boom. That does not work. Of course calling the function pointer of AbstractAPI onto an API instance calls the empty AbstractAPI method. Nothing happens. Is there a way to make this work?

How about a lambda function?

how would that work? can you give a code example?

Something like function_pointer = lambda api: api.create(). Then function_pointer(ConcreteAPIInstance).

There's a paradox in your question, you say you don't have access to your API instance, but want to call its methods. That, or I'm not getting what you are trying to achieve. What is ConcreteAPIInstance is you do not have access to your API instance. And if you have access to ConcreteAPIInstance and know you want to call create(), then what's wrong with ConcreteAPIInstance.create()?

Nothing paradoxical in it. The decision to which of the methods I want to call is in another point in time (and thread) than when I'm actually calling it.

Rather than directly referencing the abstract class method function_pointer=AbstractAPI.create, you can write a function that calls the named create() method on a given object.
function_pointer = lambda api : api.create()

or
def function_pointer(api):
    return api.create()


One approach would be to use operator.methodcaller to lookup the named method on a given object at the time of a call:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from operator import methodcaller

class AbstractAPI(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def create(self):
        pass

class API(AbstractAPI):
    def create(self):
        print("create")

function_pointer=methodcaller('create')
function_pointer(API())

This outputs:
create

